# Problems with drop down menu and its functions

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have created a simple drop down menu, with functions in it. And then I realized that after I execute functionA, I could not execute it again. I have to execute functionB(another function) before being able to execute functionA again... May I know how can I solve this problem? Below are my codes.

Thanks!

```
function changeForm(the_form)
{
    window.location = the_form;
}

 //Add Markers by Latitude and Longitude, automatically
  //Listen for click
  function marker()
      {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
     addMarker(event.latLng);
   });
      }
                // Place markers in by click
                function addMarker(location) {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: location,
              map: map,
              title:"Specified Location",
              icon: 'images/greenPoint.png'
                  });
              markersArray.push(marker);
                 }


  // Choose By Latitude and Longitude, manually
  function admarker()
{

var lat = prompt("Enter latitude (-90 to 90)", "0");
while ((lat < -90) || (lat > 90))
    {
        alert("Latitude must be between -90 to 90");
        var lat = prompt("Enter latitude (-90 to 90)", "0");
    }

var lng = prompt("Enter longitude (-180 to 180)", "0");
while  ((lng < -180) || (lng > 180))
    {
        alert("Longitude must be between -180 to 180");
        var lng = prompt("Enter latitude (-180 to 180)", "0");
    }

lat = parseInt(lat);
lng = parseInt(lng);

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        clickable: true,
        title:"Specified Location",
        icon: 'images/bluePoint.png'
        })

var infiwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Place where you have chosen!"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(){
     infiwindow.open(map,marker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout',function(){
    infiwindow.close(map,marker);
});
```

}

```
<form name = "formTwo">
<select name = "the_select" onChange = "changeForm(this.value);">
<option value = "#">- - Add Markers By Lat & Long - -</option>
<option value = "javascript:admarker()">Add Markers Manually</option>
<option value = "javascript:readMarker()">Add Markers Automatically</option>

</select></form>
```

Comment: You need to format that again. Use the 101010 icon to indent it 4 spaces so it shows as code

Comment: could you also please post the code of `functionA` and `functionB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code gets run when the value of the select box *changes*, and of course once you've selected an option, just clicking it again doesn't *change* the value.

You can probably fix it by just adding `this.selectedIndex = 0;` to your `onChange`:

```
<select name = "the_select" onChange = "changeForm(this.value); this.selectedIndex = 0;">
```

...but **wow** is that a convoluted way to run code. Rather than actually storing code in the `value` attribute, can I suggest storing a command there (more in the style of the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)) and then having `change_form` handle translating that into the actual code to run? Here's a minimalist reworking of that ([live example](http://jsbin.com/uguse4)):

```
<form name = "formTwo">
<select name = "the_select" onChange = "changeForm(this.value); this.selectedIndex = 0;">
<option value = "#">- - Add Markers By Lat & Long - -</option>
<option value = "adMarker">Add Markers Manually</option>
<option value = "readMarker">Add Markers Automatically</option>
</select></form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function changeForm(the_form)
  {
    switch (the_form) {
      case "adMarker":
        // Do something
        display("ad marker");
        break;

      case "readMarker":
        // Do something else
        display("read marker");
        break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you format your code and arrange it as the following it will work fine :-

I understand you want to change the form according to the option selected in the drop down menu.

it will be as that if I am right in my understanding and I hope it helps you:

--

function changeForm(the_form) 
{ 
window.location="http://mywebsite/"+the_form+".html"; 
}

Add Markers By Lat & Long 
Add Markers Manually 
Add Markers Automatically

--